# Ag-grid pagination customization

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid in my angular JS application to display my data. Actually, it's working fine, but my scenario is **i want to fetch only the first 10 records from server when the user clicked on next button, then make another service call to get next 10 records.**

Answer (score 1):

This example https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-infinite-scrolling/#example-2-equal-pagination-page-size-and-large-infinite-block-si is exactly what you need.

Comment: @Joginaidu Have you got update on the query?